# Dapper.NET: should variable names be the same as parameter names?

Tags: dapper

I use Dapper.NET, should variable names be the same as parameter names?
For example:

```
int id = 123;
string name = "abc";
connection.Execute("insert [KeyLookup](Id, Name) values(@id, @name)",
    new { id, name });
```

This works fine.
But what to do if I have parameters with different names:

```
int user_id = 123;
string user_name = "abc";
connection.Execute("insert [KeyLookup](Id, Name) values(@id, @name)",
    new { user_id, user_name }); // -?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you just substitute the names in the parameter object:

```cs
int user_id = 123;
string user_name = "abc";
connection.Execute("insert [KeyLookup](Id, Name) values(@id, @name)",
    new { id = user_id, name = user_name }); // -?
```